# VBA stops printing values in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro to take values from an external simulation tool and prints the results in excel.The simulaion tool will give values only every 30 seconds and will run for days. Hence i have given a delay in VB for 30 seconds in loop. I leave it overnight for running. In the next morning i could see none of the results were updated after certain rows.But the VBA editor header shows the macro is running and the external simulation tool is also running. The last updated row in excel is not constant everytime. Why does VBA stops printing the results in excel? Any help will be much appreciated.

Sample code:

```
For l = 3 To lastrow1_mul + 2
Module4.Wait 30
nv = send_data.Call
Sheets(SecondSheetName).Range(SecondSheetCol_9 & l) = Hex(nv)
dv = DT.Call
If dv = 44 Then
Sheets(SecondSheetName).Range(SecondSheetCol_10 & l) = "A"
ElseIf dv = 54 Then
Sheets(SecondSheetName).Range(SecondSheetCol_10 & l) = "B"
Else
Sheets(SecondSheetName).Range(SecondSheetCol_10 & l) = "C"
End If
Next l
```

Module 4:

```
Function Wait(PauseTime As Single)
Dim StartTime As Single 
StartTime = Timer
While Timer < StartTime + PauseTime
DoEvents
Wend  
End Function
```

Send_data and DT are external simulation tool's functions.Variable lastrow1_mul's value is getting updated around 7000 but rows in excel stops printing around 500 itself(not constant always) .

Comment: I tried using a error catch block but none of the errors were captured.

Comment: you need to provide some code / examples

Comment: @PhilipABarnes Sorry for asking this.. how can i add a piece of code here. I tried copy pasting here but code comes like a paragraph.

Comment: edit your original post, dont add in the comments. Also you can then format as code from one of the icons

Comment: @PhilipABarnes Thanks Barnes. Sample code  updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Timer' i used in the code was the culprit. Timer counts the seconds elapsed(in fractions) since midnight. So it will not update when the time becomes 00.00.00. So the wait function i wrote will keep on waiting!
Here is the solution

```
Function Wait()
Dim StartSecond As Single
Dim EndSecond
StartSecond = Now

EndSecond = DateAdd("s", 30, Now)

While Now < EndSecond
DoEvents
Wend

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

looks OK but look at using Application.OnTime shown below. Also what happens if the simulation hasnt returned data, shoudnt you build in a bigger, maybe 45 second intervals?

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "RunProcess"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the funtion of RunProcess here. It doesn't wait for 30 seconds and hits the Send_data.Call and throws Run time error 424-Object required. Simulation is working fine. I can see it in its window. By introducing more delay i'll tend to lose values from the 3rd call itself.(at 90 seconds i should have got 3 values out of simulation but by using 45 seconds delay i would get only 2 values.)

Comment: your code works fine and without seeing the big picture its difficult for me to suggest. What is the external simulation tool? You will lose values anyway as if the process takes 1 second after 15 minutes this adds another 30 seconds to your elapsed time. I would look at the simul tool and find out if messages can be queued or you can respond to events fired by the tool.

Comment: Its Vector CANalyzer tool. Mainly used in automotive industries. Can you please explain how i'll lose values after 15 minutes by using the exact delay?I didn't get your point.

Comment: simul tool gives values every 30 seconds but your process takes more than 30 seconds to run as it takes 30 seconds + time of the code to run. So if the "code to run" takes 1 second then every 15 minutes you will be delayed by 30 seconds and miss a value. This is not a SO question unfortunately and is too specific for me to provide a suitable answer

Comment: Thanks Barnes. I'll try using an array in simulation tool to receive all values and try to call that array from vb every 3 minutes(for 5 values). In this case the probability of missing values will be less i guess. Any other better suggesions?

Comment: the simul tool should just keep populating the array and when you go to read the array you can clear / empty it after use. This way you will never miss a simul result.